# .Net core microservices query from many services

Tags: .net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a .net core 5 microservices project, the client has a search module which will query the data from many objects, these objects are in many services.

first microservice for products.
in this microservice has table product {productid,  productname }.

second microservice for vendors.
in this microservice has table account {verndorId, vendorName}.

third microservice for purchase
in this microservice has table purchase {title, productid(this id comes from product table in first microservcice), accountid (this id comes from account table in secount microservice)}.

Now : the user want to search for the purchase where product name like "clothes" and vendorname like "x";

who I can do this query throw microservice pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking a monolithic system and slapping service interfaces on top of each table will just make your life hell as you will begin to implement that database logic yourself - like in this question where you try to recreate database joins.

Putting aside that it looks like your partitioning to services doesn't sound right (or needed) for this case. considering purchases describe events that happened (even if they are later deleted) they can capture a state of the product or the vendor. so you can augment the data in the purchases to represent the product and vendor data that were right at the time of the purchase. This will isolate purchase queries to the purchase service and will have the added benefit of preserving history when products/vendors evolve over time.

Comment: thank you for your answer, In my case it just not purchase module, I have fully financial system under development right now what I understand the microservices pattern is not good for these type of systems, right??

Comment: not necessarily - but simplistic break into services will not work well. In a lot of microservices even if you partition services for minimizing  cross service dependencies you still need central reporting - I usually do that by building a datamart that gets data from all services see https://freecontent.manning.com/wp-content/uploads/aggregated-reporting.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Considering this case you have to build at least 3 Queue Managers in your Message Queue service integration for Purchase, Vendor and Products.
And setup the Request and Reply queues.

Now those request and reply of the data can be in either JSON or XML however you like.

You need to create a listener which will be responsible to listen to the reply queues and you can create something like SignalR streaming to continuous listen.

Once all the integeration is completed you can directly inject the result in your Client application.